# Как установить цвет строк в select в Chrome

Tags: html, css

Наверное я не понимаю простой вещи

```
<select>
<option style='background: #009966; color: #FFF;'></option>
</select>
```

в Firefox работает - в Chrome нет.

Comment: Никак. Воспользуйтесь поиском

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Каждый браузер очень по разному понимает и показывает `select`, в iOS вообще все по-другому будет. Если вы хотите 100% кроссбраузерности, вам нужно воспользоваться одни из многих JS-скриптов, которые подменяют верстку на `ul>li` (например), а дальше вы их уже разукрашиваете как хотите.

Answer (score 0):

Всё работает же:

```css
option {
  background: #009966;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>123</option>
  <option>123</option>
  <option>123</option>
  <option>123</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ваш код у меня не работает, и через песочницу также.

Comment: Какой браузер вместе с версией? У меня Yandex Browser 43.0.2357.2877 (32 бит) - работает.

Comment: Версия 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit) google chrome. у пользователей тоже перестало работать несколько месяцев назад.